# how do I label vertices in the following octahedron?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(-.3cm,-.2cm)}, % direction z gets projected to; can also change x,y
                                       % use cm to specify non-transformed coordinates
                    line join=round, line cap=round % makes the corners look nicer
                   ]
  \draw (0,1,0) -- (-1,0,0) -- (0,-1,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (-1,0,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,1,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (-1,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! next time please provide complete small document called "minimal working example (mwe)"  beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. in mwe preamble should contain only necessary packages and your definitions, which are essential to your problem. help us to help you!

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

[image]

it is very simple, just add `node` to octahedron vertices. i didn't bother with selection of vertices' names (labels):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(-.3cm,-.2cm)}, % direction z gets projected to; can also change x,y
                                       % use cm to specify non-transformed coordinates
                    line join=round, line cap=round, % makes the corners look nicer
                    every node/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}
                   ]
  \draw ( 0,1,0) node[above] {A} --
        (-1,0,0) node [left] {B} --
        (0,-1,0) node[below] {C} --
        ( 1,0,0) node[right] {D} --
        ( 0,1,0) --
        ( 0,0,1) node[below left] {E} --
        (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (-1,0,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,1,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (-1,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick follow up. If I wanted to show a line from  a point in the center of one of the faces say A. And map that point across the center of the octahedron  to its opposite face. Basically, symmetry of a pair of faces. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user147272, sory, i cant figured out what you like to have. this is not mentioned in your question. actually, you ask new question what id better to do with question not with comment.